# How Can I Change What The Wordpress Search Bar Searches?

Tags: php, wordpress, search

You know how when you search on a Wordpress site.. you get like "www.website.com/?s=".. How can I change what the search bar searches.
For example.. I want to change the search bar to search Google.. So like it searches.. "www.google.com/?q=" instead of "/?s="

I am using the Readr theme.

I have tried multiple things but nothing hasn't worked yet

Comment: What DID you try? The plugin(?) yuo tried to write, can you show us the relevant code from it?

Answer (score 0):

You can make changes to your search form by creating or customizing your theme's `searchform.php` file (there are some alternative ways to do that too).  See this writeup from the codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_search_form

There are also plenty of search plugins available for WordPress, that offer alternative functionality to the built-in search.  One is "Search By Google."  https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-google/

Comment: There is no "searchform.php" in my theme.

Comment: So customize your theme and add one. Or use one of the plugins.

Comment: what should i put the in the "searchform.php"